# how to use dbms_scheduler to run the job every 30 minutes

Tags: oracle

I am using oracle DB ,  now as i am monitoring the performance of oracle DB which is connected to my java application , so rite now i have to monitor the count of active connections in DB at regular intervals lets say after every 30 minutes  below is the query which return me the count of active users along with there name and count

```
select osuser, count(osuser) as active_conn_count 
from v$session 
group by osuser 
order by active_conn_count desc
```

now please  advise how can i make an schedule a job in scheduler in oracle DB itself that will get triggered at every 30 minutes .

Comment: have you tried anything? Please post your code and the issues with it

Comment: In addition, what do you want the background job to do with the results of the `select` statement?  Are you trying to write this data to a table, for example?

Comment: @Aleksej Thanks for the advise but request you to please i am a new bie to the world of oracle and not aware of how to configure job in DBMS_scheduler , request you to please advise n detail bit

Comment: 2Justin Cave Thanks for your advise I simply want to write this in a text file but every time the record will be appended in that Thanks

Comment: @user1881169 - OK.  It seems odd for a job that monitors the database to write to a file rather than a table but it's certainly possible (assuming you want the file to exist on the database server).  Do you already have a stored procedure that uses `utl_file` to write the results of this query to a file?   And you're just trying to schedule that procedure to run using `dbms_scheduler`?

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest to keep your statistics in a table (say `my_log_table`), in that case schedule would look something like this:

```
begin
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
         job_name             => 'keep_stats',
         job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
         job_action           => 'begin insert into my_log_table (mUser,mCnt) (select osuser, count(osuser) as active_conn_count from v$session group by osuser  order by active_conn_count desc);commit;end;',
         start_date           => timestamp '2016-11-07 19:00:00',
         repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=30;',
         enabled              => TRUE);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are pretty much examples about dbms_scheduler. It's easy to submit a recurring job. But actually you do not need to do that! Oracle already stores tons of data about database performance, it will be easier and much more accurate to use these statistics. 
Take a look at the [active_session_history](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/active-session-history) over here.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

repeat_interval => 'FREQ=HOURLY; BYMINUTE=0,30; BYSECOND=0 ', -

Comment: This is not a good answer, please format your code, and add an explanation

Answer (score 0):

First, you create a schedule.

```
dbms_scheduler.create_schedule( schedule_name   => 'EVERY_1ST_SATURDAY'
                              , repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1 SAT;BYHOUR=2;BYMINUTE=0'
                              , start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP
                              , comments        => '1st Saturday of the month 2am.'
                              );
```

Optionally, you create a program:

```
dbms_scheduler.create_program( program_name       => 'GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS'
                             , program_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE'
                             , program_action      => 'dbms_stats.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS'
                             , number_of_arguments => 1
                             , enabled             => FALSE
                             , comments            => 'Gather schema''s stats (e.g. FRAMEWORK''s)'
                             );
```

... grant access to it:

```
GRANT execute ON sys.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS TO framework;
```

... and parameters for it:

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.define_program_argument ( 'GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS', 1 , 'ownname', 'VARCHAR2', 'FRAMEWORK' );
```

Secondly, you create a job:

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB ( job_name      => 'FRAMEWORK.GATHER_FRAMEWORK_STATS_JOB1'
                          , program_name  => 'SYS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS'
                          , schedule_name => 'SYS.EVERY_1ST_SATURDAY'
                          , enabled       => TRUE
                          , auto_drop     => FALSE
                          , comments      => 'Gather FRAMEWORK''s stats on 1st Saturday of the month.'
                          );
```